# C++ convert string of hex into char * of hex

Tags: c++

I have truly searched high and low. I feel like somehow I am just missing something so truly simple.

Oh well, here it goes:

```
string x = "1234";
```

AND

```
string y = "\x12\x34";
```

I want to turn x into y.

There is a c library I am using that only accepts y, but x won't work.

I create hex strings with the openssl/sha.h library and I want to pass them in like y.

This has to be possible and I am just missing something.

Comment: First of all, please clearly indicate whether your language is C or C++.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I doubt that a C library would accept only strings of the form `"\x12\x34"`. Please [edit] your question and tell us more about that C library.

Comment: What do you want in case of "234"? I.e. an odd number of characters in the string.

Comment: What keeps you from copying X to Y character by character, inserting an additional `\x` every other character?

Comment: @Yunnosch `\x` followed by hex is a escape sequence

Comment: @PasserBy True and that is one of the things I wanted to trigger thoughts about.

Answer (score -1):

Going on some irc channels, I got some help finally:

```
char nibble(char c) {
  if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
   return c - '0';
  return 10 + (c - 'a');
}

string stringToHex(string s) {
  string o;
  for (size_t i=0 ; i<s.size() ; i+=2){
    char c = (nibble(s[i]) << 4) | nibble(s[i+1]);
    o.push_back(c);
  }
  return o;
}



   string s = "1234";
   string h = "\x12\x34";
   string o = stringToHex(s);
   cout << "s " << s << endl;
   cout << "h " << h << endl;
   cout << "o " << o << endl;
   cout << "o == h " << (o == h) << endl;
```